# HTML Scrollable selectable table loaded by query

Tags: html, css

I have a page which is split into left and right halves. On the right is a single-column table 20 characters wide of customer names (CustList) which is filled by a query when the page is loaded and from which a user can select a customer and have those customer details fill a form in the left half (CustAmend). The User amends the data and clicks a button to update the database. CustList needs to be scrollable and 30 rows should be visible.

I can’t work out how to define the CustList table - can someone please help?

Comment: Please, share what you have already tried.

Comment: I can create the table but I don’t know how to set the default visibility for 30 rows